# Use await with threading

Tags: python, multithreading, aiogram

I having a problem while using the threading. I need to output the `Start` function on a separate thread.

```
@dp.message_handler(state=UpdateTime.UpdateTime)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        th = Thread(target= Start, args=(bot, message))
        th.start()      
        await state.finish()
```

`Start` function:

```
async def Start(bot, message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'hello')
```

Error:

`RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Start' was never awaited self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs) RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `threading` with `asyncio` (in that case)

If you wanna send something in background, just use a [asyncio.create_task(...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task)

E.g.:

```py
import asyncio


@dp.message_handler(state=UpdateTime.UpdateTime)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        asyncio.create_task(
            background_task(message)
        )
    await message.answer("Hello from direct call")


async def background_task(message: types.Message):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await message.answer("Hello from background task")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Start normal function and run coroutine without await:

```
def Start(bot, message):
    asyncio.run(bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'hello'))
```

And this will make everything work.
Don't forget to import asyncio on top.